# invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8" - Talend

Tags: talend

It is a cosmic age problem, I am getting data from MySQL (Latin1) to Postgres (UTF8) and getting the invalid byte error.

My setup for all solutions:
additiona jdbc parameter for Postgres: "characterEncoding=utf8"
tDBRow_1: "SET NAMES 'utf8'"

[image]

And yes, I've checked Stack on the matter. So far nothing worked.
Options tried:
Only - "SET NAMES 'utf8'"

convert(cast(convert(data using  latin1) as binary) using utf8) as data - in iot SQL query

CONVERT(CAST(data as BINARY) USING utf8) as data - in iot SQL query

CAST(CONVERT(data USING utf8) AS binary)  - in iot SQL query

trim(both CHAR(0x00) from data) - in iot SQL query

row1.data.replace("\x00", " ") - in tMap

data.replace('\0', ' ') - in tJava

data.replaceAll("\0", "") - in tJava

What is left:
-change additional params in target to: noDatetimeStringSync=true&characterEncoding=utf8

-change additional params in target to: useOldUTF8Behavior=true

-change tDBRow_1 to SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO utf8

But I run out of the ideas at the moment, so as the Internet.

Comment: The param 'noDatetimeStringSync=true&characterEncoding=utf8 ' with the above combinations also didn't work.

Comment: The param 'useOldUTF8Behavior=true' didn't work either'. Will work with the params on the source side.

Comment: What is the query you are using in tRow conponent?